# JavaScript conditional statements not working as intended

Tags: javascript

The function doesn't display the property when firstName and property is true -  it just moves to my other conditions and displays "no contact found". However, when I place my last return "no contacts found" outside the 'for' loop, the code works perfectly.

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){

       if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){   
            return contacts[i][prop];
       }else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false){
           return "No such property";
       }else if (contacts[i].firstName !== firstName){
           return "No such contact";
       }

  }


// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about it, your code needs to look like this:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    const contact = contacts[i];

    if (contact.firstName === firstName) {
      if (contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return contact[prop];
      else return "No such property";
    }
  }

  return "No such contact";
}
```

You don't want to decide there is no such property until you know you are on the one with the right `firstName`, and you don't want to decide there is no such contact until you have gone through all the entries.

To find logical errors like this, it is often helpful to walk through your code line by line with the debugger, watching exactly what it does.

In "modern" JS style this could also be written as

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  const entry = contacts.find(contact => contact.firstName === firstName);

  return !entry ? "No such contact" : 
    entry.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? entry[prop] : "No such property";
}
```

Or, if you find the ternary (`?`) operator too hard to read, then

```
  if (!entry) return "No such contact";
  if (!entry.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return "No such property";
  return entry[prop];
```

If you intend to do a lot of these lookups, then prepare a map indexed by `firstname`:

```
const map = new Map(contacts.map(contact => [contact.firstName, contact]));
```

Now you can write your lookup in something close to O(1) time as:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  const entry = map.get(firstName);

  return entry ? "No such contact" : 
    contact.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? contact[prop] : "No such property";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the firstname of each contact ,if they are not equal you are returning as no contact exist,when kristin contact becomes unequal with the first contact it returns no contact and exists from for loop 
that's the reason when you move they are working as expected

change your code to the following

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "lastName": "Laine",
  "number": "0543236543",
  "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "number": "0994372684",
  "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Sherlock",
  "lastName": "Holmes",
  "number": "0487345643",
  "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Kristian",
  "lastName": "Vos",
  "number": "unknown",
  "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}];


function lookUpProfile(first_Name, prop) {
  var contactExists = false;
  var noProp = false;
  // Only change code below this line
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

    if (contacts[i].firstName === first_Name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      contactExists = true;
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
    if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
      noProp = true;
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
  if (!contactExists || !noProp) {
    return "No such contact";
  }

}


// Change these values to test your function
var res = lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
console.log(res);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This code will falsely report "no such property" in the case that an earlier entry which does **not** match the name does not have the property. Also, the test at the end for `noProp` will have no effect, because the function returns immediately after setting `noProp` to true anyway.

Comment: Thanks will change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){

       if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){   
            return contacts[i][prop];
       }else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false){
           return "No such property";
       }else if (contacts[i].firstName !== firstName){
           return "No such contact";
       }

  }


// Only change code above this line
}
```

Remove `two else if` condition because of that it is returning from function preventing from further lookup. 
When array is looking for 0th element, condition wont be satisfied so it will go to `3rd else if` block where it will return from the function. `Return` should be written after for loop.

Comment: When array is looking for 0th element, condition wont be satisfied so it will go to 3rd else if block where it will return from the function. return should be written after for loop.